# Regarding the impact of length increase of power cord on the EMC-EMI performance of electronics device

Tags: emc, compliance

Is there any impact of the length increase of the power cord on the EMC-EMI performance of the electronic devices? If yes then how it affects the performance? Are there any standards for the length of Power Cords?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clarify ‘power cords’. Mains power cords? If so, the length of the power cord is insignificant to the fixed wiring in the house/office. DC power cords are usually the length from the wall wart/psu or the designated default length in the CE standard (3m??). Can the length affect enc/emi? Yes.

Comment: Hello Kartman,                                                                                                                                            I am talking about the detachable AC Power cords which are provided with the AC-operated devices.

Comment: You should put that clarification in your question. As I said, the length of the power cord is insignificant to the length of the fixed mains wiring.   It’s not like the fixed wiring is shielded or otherwise different to the power cord. However, the conductor size may have an effect due to voltage drop.

Comment: Sorry, Can you please simplify it? Thanks.

Comment: 1.possible impact. 2.depends on actual device. 3. Yes.

Comment: Thank you Kartman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  In the EMC testing lab, the cable is terminated into a LISN (Line Impedance Stabilization Network).  Wavelengths on par with the length of the cable, may be radiated.  (Lower frequencies being radiated less, as the cable and other material makes an electrically short mono/di-pole.)   A shorter cable may radiate less, or starting from higher frequencies.

This may not be a very significant effect anyway, as longer cables are generally folded up such that the cable does not lie on the ground.  The folding will introduce inductance and have an impact on radiated frequencies, but not in any obvious way (notching some frequencies but promoting others).

In any case, the fact that it depends, is a good reason to keep the configuration consistent and well documented.  (Take lots of photos in the lab, and if possible, fix items to a board to maintain orientation between test outings.)

Whether this matters in the real world -- who knows.  Mains wiring is largely an extension of the power cord itself, ground isn't a ground plane; the power network can be arbitrary (long, branching, routing parallel to other circuits, etc.); etc.  The standards presumably are constructed such that, given natural variation, actual emissions (including radiation below 30MHz) are only rarely problematic.

As for standards, basically: distribute the product with the cord, or power adapter, etc. it was tested with (and recommend such in the product manual).

Comment: is it true that depending on the specced cable length (in your own product data sheet), different tests can become necessary? Thats what one test house told me once..

Comment: I'm not sure what other tests would become necessary; but each combination should be tested, I think. Mind, I am no NRTL buff, there may be standards out there that demand more.